# Extend UIPickerView to change title color

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I would like all UIPickerViews in an app to have white text. I can make it work fine for an individual pickerview, but I would like to have it apply to all occurrences.

I got this far...

```
extension UIPickerView {
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString? {
    let titleData = ?????
    let colorTitle = NSAttributedString(string: titleData, attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor()])
}
```

However, I don't want to actually change the text... just the color. How can I grab the title (text) for the specified row so that I can returned it as an NSAttributedString?

Thanks.

Comment: Make a class XYUIPickerView and repalce all UIPickerView with your XYUIPickerView in Storyboard/XIB or source code.

Comment: ... but what do I modify in the new class to create the NSAttributedString? I would still have the same issue as above. I need to know what to replace the ????? with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a subclass of UIDatePicker and overriding the addSubView method. The code below is working well for me.

```
class ColoredDatePicker: UIDatePicker {
    var changed = false
    override func addSubview(view: UIView) {
        if !changed {
            changed = true
            self.setValue(UIColor.whiteColor(), forKey: "textColor")
        }
        super.addSubview(view)
    }
}
```